# How to pass variable values from one page to another page using AJAX and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to pass variable values from one page to another page using AJAX and jQuery.

I have categories like this main category users,names.first names ...etc and sub menu

```
A|B|C|D|E|F||G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ajax` you will have to have some server side language such as php, asp to process your data and return some some response. **[See this jquery ajax tutorial, good for beginners.](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). You can pass the data in as an argument.